# Keystone.js Admin UI - no fields in a form

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I've created such a model:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Page = new keystone.List('Page', {
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'menuTitle', unique: true },
    map: { name: 'menuTitle' },
});

Page.add({
    keyword: { type: Types.Key, required: true, initial: false },
    slug: { type: Types.Key, required: true, initial: false },
    type: { type: Types.Select, options: 'textpage, projects, services, contacts, homepage', default: 'textpage' },
    menuTitle: { type: String, required: true, initial: false },
    pageTitle: { type: String },
    pageContent: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 },
    seoTitle: { type: String },
    seoKeywords: { type: String },
    seoDescription: { type: String },
    isActive: { type: Types.Boolean }
});

Page.defaultColumns = 'keyword, slug, menuTitle, isActive';
Page.register();
```

I expected it will generate a list of objects and a form to create these objects.
But the form has no fields. [image]

What am I doing wrong? Or what else should I do to get a form with all my fields?

Comment: The name of the `menuTitle` field is misspelled, which you reference in the List's `autokey` option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, you're not seeing any fields because you have the `initial` option set to `false` on them all.

`initial` defaults to `false`, except for the "name" field - i.e. by default a field with the path `name` or a path that matches the mapping you've given Keystone for `name`, in your case `menuTitle`.

So normally your `menuTitle` field would show up, expect you're explicitly telling it not to with the `initial: false` setting.

To get fields to show up, simply set the ones you want to `initial: true`, like this:

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Page = new keystone.List('Page', {
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'menuTitle', unique: true },
    map: { name: 'menuTitle' },
});

Page.add({
    keyword: { type: Types.Key, required: true, initial: true },
    type: { type: Types.Select, options: 'textpage, projects, services, contacts, homepage', default: 'textpage' },
    menuTtle: { type: String, required: true, initial: true },
    pageTitle: { type: String, initial: true },
    pageContent: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 400 },
    seoTitle: { type: String },
    seoKeywords: { type: String },
    seoDescription: { type: String },
    isActive: { type: Types.Boolean }
});

Page.defaultColumns = 'keyword, slug, menuTitle, isActive';
Page.register();
```

Also worth noting that you don't need to actually add the `slug` field; it's automatically added to the schema for you because of your `autokey` settings.